# Hard question about functions

Tags: functions

This is the final question about function on the Chinese senior-high mathematics exam. Try to see if you can solve it!

> Given that $f(x)=(\cos x-1)e^{-x}$, $g(x)=ax^2+(1-e^x)x\quad(a\in\Bbb R)$.

Questions:

1. When $x\in(0,\pi)$, evaluate the minimum of $f(x)$;
2. Given that the inequality
   $$xf(x)\ge \frac{g(x)}{e^x}$$
   is valid for all $x\in[-\frac\pi2,+\infty)$, determine the range of parameter $a$.

I will post my own answer below. Feel free to edit it or post your own ones.

Comment: I suggest that you make the title more informative and specific to the matter of the question. And don't share your answer so quickly, give others chance as well :)

Comment: you can just ignore my answer actually, people have eyelids :)

Comment: I just don't understand why you guys vote the question negatively so positively. Just because the former title? We are here sharing maths instead of being annoying and picky...

Comment: I didn't downvote... But I believe the possible reasons for others' vote could be 1. Your question isn't focused (one post should ask one question)... 2. The title isn't specific still (it's a very general one)

Comment: @YANGyu I have already explained why such posts are so badly received in one of your [other posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4828630/inequality-proof-about-a-function-with-an-extremum). Hope it clears your confusion.

Answer (score -1):

1. Calculating the minimum of $f(x)$

---

Calculate the derivative of $f(x)$
$$f'(x)=(-\sin x)e^{-x}-(\cos x-1)e^{-x}$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(x)=(1-\sin x-\cos x)e^{-x}$$
$$\Rightarrow f'(x)=(1-\sqrt2\sin(x+\frac\pi4))e^{-x}$$
When $x\in(0,\frac\pi2)$, we have $\sin(x+\frac\pi4)\in(\frac{\sqrt2}2,1)$, which means
$$f'(x)\lt0$$
When $x\in(\frac\pi2, \pi)$, we have $\sin(x+\frac\pi4)\in(-\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt2}2)$, which means
$$f'(x)\gt0$$
Thus, $f(x)$ has a local minimum at $x=\frac\pi2$,
$$[f(x)]_{min}=f(\frac\pi2)=-e^{-\frac\pi2}$$

2. Determining the range of $a$

---

$$xf(x)\ge \frac{g(x)}{e^x}$$
$$\iff(\cos x-1)xe^{-x}\ge\frac{ax^2+(1-e^x)x}{e^x}$$
$$\iff x(\cos x-1)\ge ax^2+(1-e^x)x$$

- If $x=0$, it is obvious that this inequality is valid for all $a$.
- If $x\in[-\frac\pi2,0)$, we have
  $$e^x+\cos x-ax-2\le0$$
- If $x\in(0, +\infty)$, we have
  $$e^x+\cos x-ax-2\ge0$$

Let $h(x)=e^x+\cos x-ax-2$, we have
$$h(0)=0$$
which means that we must have $h'(0)\ge0$, otherwise the two inequalities above won't be satisfied.
$$h'(x)=e^x-\sin x-a$$
$$h'(0)=1-a\ge0$$
$$\Rightarrow a\le1$$
Consider to prove the situation when $a=1$,
$$h(x)=e^x+\cos x-x-2\quad h'(x)=e^x-\sin x-1$$
When $x\in(0,+\infty)$, according to the useful inequlity $e^x\gt x+1$,
$$h'(x)\gt x-\sin x\gt 0$$
$$\Rightarrow h(x)\ge 0\quad x\in(0,+\infty)$$
When $x\in[-\frac\pi2,0)$, let $h'(x_0)=0$, the maximum of $h(x)$ must be at $x=-\frac\pi2$ or $x=x_0$
$$h(-\frac\pi2)=e^{-\frac\pi2}+\frac\pi2-2\lt0$$
$$e^{x_0}=\sin x_0+1$$
$$h(x_0)=\sin x_0+\cos x_0-1=\sqrt2\sin(x_0+\frac\pi4)-1$$
$$\sin(x_0+\frac\pi4)\in(-\frac{\sqrt2}2,\frac{\sqrt2}2)$$
$$\Rightarrow h(x_0)\lt0$$
$$\Rightarrow h(x)\le0$$
Thus, we have prove that the inequality is valid when $a=1$， then it must be valid for all $a\le1$. (consider the term $ax$ as a straight line and $e^x+\cos x-2$ as a curve and imagine the line rotating clockwise when $a$ decreases from $1$)
$$a\le1$$

Comment: I know that this is not an elegant one. So please share your idea with me.